# Cannot access mysql as user. What can I do?

Tags: mysql

I see this error when I startup mysql:

```
mysql
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'jwan'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

This is my mysql version:

```
mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.23
```

What can I do? Is using sudo bad here to do?

I inherited this rails project and this is my database.yml:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: some_database
  username: root
  password:
  host: localhost
  port: 3306
```

Comment: yes, using sudo is very bad, here. Create an account with the minimum necessary rights for your application to interact with the database.

Comment: What are the schema permissions for that user?

Comment: I'm using a mac with the mysql2 gem.

Comment: Which password you set for the MySQL ? At the time of installation

Answer (score 0):

If this is a fresh MySQL installation, you don't have a user account created yet. Try logging in as the root user: `mysql -u root`. The first thing you should do is set a password for the root account. Then you can create user accounts.

If this is an existing database, ask the administrator which user account and password you are supposed to use. Then access with `mysql -u YourUserName -p`. It will ask for a password.

Comment: `mysql -u root` does not work but `mysql -u root -p` does and I entered in my user password when I login to my mac. How do I create user accounts?

Comment: create user (...) identifed by (...) https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/adding-users.html